# I tried to get title from this site (http://www.itslaw.com), it was loading by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

Here is my code, I using Python to get information, I use proxies, headers, session to simulate, but I kept getting 501.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
from goose import Goose
from goose.text import StopWordsChinese
import json
import time


class ItSlaw(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'XXXX'                
        self.headers = {'XXXX'}
        self.result = None
        self.keyword = None
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def reset(self, keyword):
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.result = None

    def fetch(self):
        url = self.url.format(keyword='self.keyword',keywordcopy='self.keyword') 
        res = []
        time.sleep(3)
        proxies = {"http": "14.111.148.1"}
        r = self.session.get(url, proxies=proxies)
        print r.status_code
        completed_url = 'http://www.itslaw.com/' + 'url'
        g = Goose({'stopwords_class': StopWordsChinese})
        article = g.extract(url=completed_url)
        content = article.cleaned_text
        res.append()
        self.result = res
        return self.result

    def get_result(self):
        return self.result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/):

1. Install selenium for Python using `pip`. 
   For Linux(Ubuntu/Debian) it looks:

   `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

   `sudo pip install selenium`

(!)*You have to google how to do it for your OS*

2. then just run this code

> ```
> import unittest
> from selenium import webdriver
>
> class GetTitle(unittest.TestCase):
>
>     def setUp(self):
>         self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>
>     def test_get_title(self):
>         driver = self.driver
>         driver.get("http://www.itslaw.com/")
>         print "Title is: ", driver.title
>
>     def tearDown(self):
>         self.driver.close()
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     unittest.main()
> ```

```
>>> Title is: 无讼案例|无讼名片-打造中国最大的互联网律师名片、案例检索服务平台
```